# IE8 issue - elements animate with wrong transform-origin

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, css-transitions, css-transforms

I currently have one big main circle. From this big circle im doing some animation with some lines appearing from the center point of the big circle and then rotating around the big circle with soem different degress.

Im using prefixes like the following to define the transfer-origin:

```
transform-origin: center bottom;
-moz-transform-origin: center bottom; /* Firefox */
-ms-transform-origin: center bottom; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform-origin: center bottom; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform-origin: center bottom; /* Opera */
```

This works fine in all browsers except IE8 and downwards - tried a few different things to target and fix this in IE8, but no luck. Any suggestions.

Example Fiddle of the working animation here:
http://jsfiddle.net/R5CDv/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working in IE8 and below, because the `transform` property [is only supported from IE9+](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3styleproperties/p/transform-origin.htm).

For IE8 and below, one solution which could be useful would be using [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - check out this tutorial on [implementing transform-origin](http://someguynameddylan.com/lab/transform-origin-in-internet-explorer.php) on older versions of IE using it.

Comment: Nver figured out how to use this - but guess its lack of HTML skill - but accepting since the answer surely seems to be present here